# Error from Debugger: Previous frame inner to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame)

Tags: iphone, debugging, breakpoints

I am getting the following debugger error when I encounter a breakpoint on the device:

Error from Debugger: Previous frame inner to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame)

This occurs when the app hits a breakpoint.  If I hit the continue button in the debugger, it continues happily until the next breakpoint, when it pops up the same issue.

What does this message mean, and more importantly how can I fix it?  I have been debugging this app for a long time without ever encountering this error.

I tried a clean build, as well as rebooting my Mac.  I am on XCode 3.2.3, iOS 4.0.1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I started having this problem also, and for me it was caused by LLVM code generation. I switched the compiler setting in my target from "LLVM GC 4.2" to "GCC 4.2", did a clean rebuild, and the debugger was happy again.

This can also be caused by stack corruption, so its possible you may have a legitimate bug. In my case though, I couldn't set breakpoints anywhere, anytime, even in applicationDidFinishLaunching:. That pointed the finger at a build setting.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I also had to switch to regular GCC 4.2 in all my cross-project references. If any code included in the build from anywhere had LLVM enabled, the debugger could not read the stack.

Comment: That was it, thanks.  I'm disappointed though, since LLVM supposedly produces faster binaries.  I guess I'll have to wait until they get the kinks sorted out.

Comment: I agree. I have it enabled on my Release builds only, and use the old GCC for Debug.

Comment: You are a star! Switching to GCC 4.2 made my breakpoints start working also!

Thanks!